# gstreamer textoverlay covers entire stream

Tags: bash, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am using gstreamer in a qt application, but it behaves the same way using a gst-launch command.  The following pipeline works for displaying my video:

```
gst-launch-1.0 tcamsrc ! xvideo/x-bayer,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=15/1  ! tcamautoexposure ! tcamwhitebalance ! bayer2rgb ! videoconvert ! xvideosink
```

But if I try to add a simple ***textoverlay*** it covers the entire stream.

```
gst-launch-1.0 tcamsrc ! xvideo/x-bayer,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=15/1  ! tcamautoexposure ! tcamwhitebalance ! bayer2rgb ! videoconvert ! textoverlay font-desc="Sans 24" text="test string" valignment=top halignment=left shaded-background=true ! xvideosink
```

I have been able to add image overlays before with ***gdkpixbufoverlay***, but I really want to add text in this instance.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I can also swith the silent property of textoverlay and either way I get no video.

Comment: @bashonly yeah that was just a typo